# Pan a large image inside a div without using mouseover

Tags: jquery, image, css, html

I'm having quite a problem here. I have a div of width:800px and height:400px; Inside the div i have an image of width:800px and height:600px; since the div is set to overflow hidden, the bottom 200px of the image is hidden. How can I pan this image automatically as the image loads, without having to mouseover, so that the user can see the whole image, even thought the height is just 400px. i want the image to pan automatically (vertically or both ways)? Is there a jquery plugin i can use? Remember, this has to be done without mouseover, as soon as the page or image loads. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ae2kV/1/

Comment: I need to pan it, not scale it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this image panning samples with codes: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/39/
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this is what i had in mind, but how do you implement this for a single image and i dont want a slideshow (less code)

Comment: Then you have to remove the other images or other image tags and replace yours. The HTML code consists only the images which will be shown. What makes the code long is the panning effects in the JavaScript code which you can copy and/or manipulate if you want. Good luck!

Comment: heyy, i hav one more doubt, if we use a single image, its pans at first and then jus stops. doenst loop, any workaround for that?

Comment: It's because the code in the class carousel looks for next img tag, fades, then shows the next image. You can replace that part, or try adding more img tags with the same image source if you don't want to work too much with the JavaScript code.

Comment: link is broken btw